# Success message is not showing and url is not redirected to activate.php?success

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time figuring out an error with my PHP User/registration site.
After registration an email with an activation link is sent, and when the link is clicked it successfully activates the account, but it is not showing the success message.

If i copy/paste the activation link in the browser and change a letter in either the email or email-code that is in the link, it will successfully give me all the error messages.

activation link looks like this:

**http://website.com/activate.php?email=useremail@website.com&email_code=2631df446b129480abdbf54f08e8c494**

This is the code for my activate.php

```
<?php 
include 'core/init.php';
logged_in_redirect();
include 'includes/overall/header.php';
?>

<?php 
if (isset($_GET['success']) == true && empty($_GET['success']) == true) {
    ?>
<h3>Thanks, your account has been activated..</h3>
<p>You're free to log in!</p>
<?php
    header('Location: activate.php?success');
    exit();
} else if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['email_code']) === true) {

$email      = trim($_GET['email']);
$email_code = trim($_GET['email_code']);

if (email_exists($email) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Ooops something went wrong, and we couldn\'t find that email adress!';
    } else if (activate($email, $email_code) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'We had problems activating your account';
    } if (empty($errors) === false) {
?>
    <h2>Ooops...</h2>
<?php
    echo output_errors($errors);
} else {
    header('Location: activate.php?success');
    exit();
}
} else {
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}
?>

<?php include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

Why won't it give me the success message and redirect?

The URL doesn't change from: http://website.com/activate.php?email=useremail@website.com&email_code=2631df446b129480abdbf54f08e8c494

to:
website.com/activate.php?success

Comment: empty($_GET['success']) == true sorry but why are you adding extra code cant you just check empty($_GET['success']) ? and isset returns true or false itself there is no need to check using == true

Comment: You should probably be using POST, you're sharing personal information by using GET, even though you redirect.

Comment: You cannot send a header after you already sent HTML. You have to do headers before anything. Also, rather than redirecting right away, you should write a 5 second redirect so the user can read your message telling them they are activated. `<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=index.php"></head>`

Comment: If I understand correctly and the above code you have with `empty($_GET['success'] == true)` within `activate.php` then if it worked you would get an infinite header redirect error. Your logic needs to be revisited.

Answer (score 0):

There is somthing fishy about this line:

```
if (isset($_GET['success']) == true && empty($_GET['success']) == true) {
```

are you sure it isnt `&& empty($_GET['success']) == false)` ?

Comment: Or better yet: `(isset($_GET['success']) && !empty($_GET['success'])`

Comment: Yea, I use the same approach to, I just added the FALSE to make the change noticable

Answer (score 0):

Never, EVER use <kbd>HTMLcode <?php PHPcode</kbd> syntax with <kbd>header</kbd> commands.
Basically: You first output a string (your HTML code), and then attempt to output headers.
**That's incorrect**. Headers need to be sent **before** anything else. What you want to do is convert whole document into a PHP (first characters of document should be <kbd><?php</kbd>) and then use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax to actually insert a blocks of HTML code, and echo them (all collect everything into one variable and echo in the last line of your code). Avoid mixing PHP with HTML like you did here at all cost.

Answer (score 0):

You have it set to if `activate == true` and empty redirect to that exact page so you would get a redirect loop.

```
if (isset($_GET['success']) == true && empty($_GET['success']) == true) {
        header('Location: activate.php?success');
        exit();
}
```

Try

```
if (isset($_GET['success']) == true && empty($_GET['success']) == true) {
       echo "It worked";
       exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test which of your criteria is failing, see below. As a side note: You don't need the parentheses in `exit` if you aren't passing a status through, you also don't need to open and close php so much, it isn't necessary:

```
<?php 
include 'core/init.php';
logged_in_redirect();
include 'includes/overall/header.php';

if (isset($_GET['success']) && !empty($_GET['success'])) {
    //in activate.php isset($_GET['success']) add this ouput, 
    //it works / not recommended and never seen.
    //echo "<h3>Thanks, your account has been activated..</h3>";
    //echo "<p>You're free to log in!</p>";
    header('Location: activate.php?success');
    exit;
} else if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['email_code'])) {
    $email = trim($_GET['email']);
    $email_code = trim($_GET['email_code']);
    if (email_exists($email) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Ooops something went wrong, and we couldn\'t find that email adress!';
    } else if (activate($email, $email_code) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'We had problems activating your account';
    } if (empty($errors) === false) {
        echo "<h2>Ooops...</h2>";
        echo output_errors($errors);
    } else {
        header('Location: activate.php?success');
        exit;
    }
} else {
    // The following 2 lines: You should see 1, 0 or nothing
    // From there you should be able to troubleshoot.        
    echo "isset: ".isset($_GET['success'])."<br>";
    echo "Empty: ".empty($_GET['success']);
    //header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
```

---

When I test the above code with `?success` it redirects fine for me.

**EDIT:**

If I understand correctly and the above code you have with `empty($_GET['success'] == true)` within `activate.php` then if it worked you would get an infinite header redirect error. Your logic needs to be revisited.

Comment: What would the meaning of output 1, 0 or nothing be?

Comment: I mean `boolean` values. 1 is `true`, 0 is `false` or nothing because it didn't get there. My code echos the `isset`'s which return `boolean` values